# Thermostat Throttle Body Heater Inlet Pipe Astra-H 55574685 or 55354563

Tags: opel, vauxhall, astra, holden, cruze

Throttle Body Heater Inlet Pipe has cracked on my Opel/Holden Astra-H 2008, engine Z18XER (chevrolet F18D4).

I need

Throttle Body Water Inlet Pipe 55354563

It will cost me about 40$

But

similar part
    55574685.
Suitable for Vauxhall Astra Insignia Cruze 1.6.

Is available only for 5$.

Would the cheap one suit my needs?

Why are they so different in price?

Based on eBay analysis.

For engine Z16XER / A16XER part 55354563 may be replaced with 25192904, 55559352, 55569809, 55574685.

For engine Z18XER, part 55354563 may be replaced with 25192905, 5826481, 5826487.

AND

Sellers claim that 55574685/25192904/55559352 is fine for Z18XER if only it comes from Zafira-B, but if you have Astra-H it will only fit Z16XER/A16XER (and not Z18XER).

[image: picture]

Comment: It seems they are two separate engines. Isn't one a 1.8 and the other a 1.6? I dont have access now, so cannot crosscheck yet.

Comment: Yes, mine engine is 1.8 and and the other one engine code is not clear. Where I look for z16xer engine part, I'm getting again 55354563 which is 40$. Where the 5$ one came from and why is it cheaper - is still a question.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 , I did it, it is working. hurray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok I have bought 55574685 for about $5.00 with free postage.

And install it on my `Astra H 2008 wagon` all right.

Just one more thing you should know.

the connector on the thermostat side is not quite the same, thus - if you have old one working, - great, you will have no worries.

If your one is broken, like in my case, you'll need a file (I used it) or a sand paper (or a knife sharpening stone) to make the side flat on the other side. See picture to see how the connector is flat on one side and round on the other?

[image]

well, in my case it was flat on the wring side, but, it is not important, because the rubber washer is way above this flat part of connector.

Anyway, it has been a week with no leak already.